# What is the best way to keep lawn alive with two big dogs?

Tags: dogs, training, pest-control, digging

I'm about to move into a brand new house with a brand new lawn and I have some concerns... First of all, I want to be able to leave my dogs outside when I go to work, but they will dig. (And I know all about waking them and playing with them and getting enough exercise and giving them toys, etc, you don't need to tell me. It doesn't matter how much I exercise them, they have a seemingly unlimited amount of energy... They're tamaskans, so they are highly intelligent and get bored easily too even though they have like a million kong toys, stuffed animals, bones, and rawhide ...). I've considered making them a sandbox, but I can see the sand slowly migrating out of the box since they will definitely be throwing it everywhere when digging... I'm thinking about putting down chicken wire. My first question is - would it be better to put it under the turf (I was told that the grass won't be rooted by the time I move in so I can lift it and place the wire if I want) or just on top of the grass? I hear it will sink into the soil and get covered by grass so it won't be visible anyways. My second question is - how much and when should I water? It gets hot in Texas. I have a sprinkler system so I can just set up a schedule. I read that is better to water deeply 2-3 times a week early in the morning (why not at night?). But because I have big dogs who will pee on the grass every day, I wonder if I should water more often but in smaller amount to prevent burn spots? But then internet also says that watering often will result in shallows grass roots that will require more water to stay alive. Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: As it's phrased now, this question is better suited for Home Improvement than for Pets. The sandbox is the only pet related topic and it's a good idea to provide your dogs with a dedicated digging site. The rest is off topic.

Comment: @Elmy what's off topic about dealing with dog burn spots?... And i did post it in home improvement first, it got moved from there.

Comment: How much to water grass in Texas has nothing to do with keeping pets. Neither does whether or not chicken wire will sink into the soil.

Comment: those are considerations necessary to take into account when answering the question ... otherwise you would complain i didn't provide enough details

Comment: This question is actually 2 questions in one. I agree the part about care of lawn belongs in home improvement.